# Cannot export System.keychain Certificate from with private key as p12 via Terminal security export command

Tags: macos, security, mojave, keychain, certificate

I have a machine certificate installed in system.keychain and want to export certificate with privet key via security export command.

But getting error :`security: SecKeychainItemExport: User interaction is not allowed.`

Command :
`security export -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -P password -t identities -f pkcs12 -o /Users/skull/Desktop/test.p12`